# Счётчик юзеров онлайн и запись в бд, PHP

Tags: php, mysql

На главной странице админки добавить показатель юзеров онлайн на сайте сейчас.
Нужно учесть

- если юзер зашел и вышел и закрыл вкладку не считать
- считаем только того у кого открыта вкладка сайта
  Задачка не приоритетная, на понимание механики.
  В данном счетчике учесть
  Каждый день вконце дня пишем сколько юзеров было на сайте - в базу данных.
- выводим число в среднем в день за неделю

Как лучше реализовать? Я записал в таблицу два параметра, это ip, date, чтобы можно было сделать выборку по времени. Подскажите как лучше реализовать ? P.S я начинающий программист.

Comment: а вы уверены что у каждого юзера свой IP ?

Comment: Если хочется узнать, что пользователь закрыл вкладку, то нужно либо вебсокет подымать, либо постоянно дергать сервер. (на самом деле просто так лучше  не делать, что бы не получить  от благодарных пользователей по голове). Но даже в этом случае есть большой шанс, что нельзя будет отследить, что пользователь "закрыл вкладку/окно". Обычно все считают по последней активности. Если пользователь открыл сайт и свернул страницу браузера, то он онлайн или не очень?

Comment: Считайте заходы. Нахождение на вкладке считайте по времени с момента последней активности (и не размахивайтесь на "час с момента захода" - выбирайте вменяемое время, ещё лучше - "за последние ... минут страницу посетили ...", хотя бы врать не придётся). Выберите способ идентификации пользователя (сеанс, куки и пр.).

Comment: Задача именно что на понимание. "показатель юзеров онлайн на сайте сейчас" - это фикция, воображаемое число. "сейчас" на сате нет ни одного. Браузер делает запрос, за долю секунды получает информацию и закрывает соединение. Число "сейчас на сайте" показывает вего лишь сколько условно разных пользователей обращались к сайту за определенный интервал времени.

Comment: Статистика по этой воображаемой цифре - это совсем отдельная тема. Но в целом направление верное. записывать дату обращения и какой-никакой идентификатор, айпи вполне подйдет. потом считать уникальных посетилелей за день. В с реднем за день получится полтора инвалида, но зато честно.

Comment: Спасибо большое